# Orthogonal matrices $A$ for which $A^n = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

Can we say that orthogonal matrices for which $P^n = I$ are necessarily permutation matrices?

I know the matrices that satisfy the condition $P^n = I$ are called periodic.  Also, permutation matrices are non-negative and orthogonal. Is the condition of non-negativity inherent in periodic matrices?

If not, Could we put restrictions on periodic matrices for them to be permutations?
Or on orthogonal periodic matrices for them to be permutations?

Any help without using the entries of the matrix will be appreciated.

I do not know much about properties of periodic matrices. It'll be a great help if someone gives better insight of such matrices.

Comment: Computing $PP^T$ involves multiplying entries of the matrix and adding the products, So what is the question?

Comment: @JCAA I meant could we think of a check which has to do with the matrix itself as a whole not with checking its entries? I mean like multiplying that kind of matrices with some matrix always give some matrices like (PJ = J) Where J is a square matrix consisting of only ones. I have edited the question further.

Comment: I think this needs to be stated more formally. But since you can always change the basis vectors, it is impossible to pin down the permutation matrices by algebraic equations alone.

Comment: @Trebor How could the ability to change the basis vectors make it impossible to Pin down the permutation matrices by algebraic equations? Could you plese elaborate?

Comment: For instance, for the algebraic equation $APB + CPPD = 0$, a change of basis means $X \mapsto \Lambda X \Lambda^{-1}$. So the whole thing become $\Lambda APB \Lambda^{-1} + \Lambda CPPD \Lambda^{-1} = 0$, which still holds, but $P$ becomes $\Lambda P \Lambda^{-1}$, which is not necessarily permutational. You can circumvent this though..

Answer (score 3):

No. These matrices are  roots of the unit matrix, not permutations. Counter example :
$ A={1\over\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1 \end{pmatrix}$

$A^4=I$

Answer (score 3):

$${\bf A} := \begin{bmatrix}\cos{\left(\frac{2 \pi}{n} \right)} & - \sin{\left(\frac{2 \pi}{n} \right)}\\\sin{\left(\frac{2 \pi}{n} \right)} & \cos{\left(\frac{2 \pi}{n} \right)}\end{bmatrix}$$

is orthogonal and ${\bf A}^n = {\bf I}_2$. However, $\bf A$ is not a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A very trivial observation is that, let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with 1 at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, and 0 elsewhere. Then $E_{1i}PE_{j1}$ is just the matrix with $P_{ij}$ at the upper left corner, and 0 elsewhere. If, additionally, you allow the use of absolute values and determinants, you can construct a huge expression, basically saying "($P_{11}=1$ and $P_{22}=1$ and ...) or ($P_{21}=1$ and $P_{12}=1$ and $P_{33}=1$ and ...)", which fulfills your criterion.

Comment: Thanks! But could we find some simple equation which is characteristic of permutation matrices not involving the entries?

Comment: @Kabir My answer actually doesn't explicitly involve the entries. It just cleverly fetched the entries out...

Comment: Fine! So you mean that the $P_{11}$ entry of the matrix can be written as $e_{1}^{T}Pe_{1}$